# tut49.html:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') why? my code is-

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Strings and String Methods</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
        <div id="conteint"></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Incidunt aspernatur itaque excepturi dolor, ab dicta. Mollitia tempora rem deleniti, nemo consectetur quos enim unde consequatur. Ipsum libero dolor alias cum, ducimus labore minus beatae.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('Conteint').innerHTML="<h3> this is an h3 heading </h3>"

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

type here

where is the problem, I can't fix
please help, the problem is tut49.html:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') why? please do a final review and check

Comment: `conteint` vs `Conteint`. It should be `document.getElementById('conteint').innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with id selector.

Replace below code:

```
document.getElementById('Conteint').innerHTML="<h3> this is an h3 
heading </h3>"
```

With This:

```
 document.getElementById('conteint').innerHTML="<h3> this is an h3 
 heading </h3>"
```

Working demo codepen link - https://codepen.io/Rohan-Kadam/pen/vYQJXEE